# Vue node Mysql – Mysql table joining

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

Hi I’m trying to make a small CRM where I storing some master data for Clients and I have made a CRUD that saves to a MySQL table called clients – so far so good.

Now I would like to register worked time within each Client, so I need arrays within arrays, but as I can see that is not possible with MySQL tables.

My idea is that when I have finished working on a task, then I (frontend) select a the **Client**, and then I select “Register time” within that **client** then I select the **Year** I have done the task, and then I select the **Month** I have done the task and then **I add a new line** with in that table **(Time sheet)** where I set the date, the name of the task and the time used or the fixed priced and save.
I have the table Clients which contains the basic master data:

**Clients** (simplified) – where I want to add the new column with **register_time**.

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| client_id | client_name | clients_phone | clients_email | register_time |  
+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|         1 |        Ford |   111-222-333 | info@ford.com |       [years] |  
|         2 |         BMW |   444-555-666 |  info@bmw.com |       [years] |  
|         3 |         KIA |   777-888-999 |  info@kia.com |       [years] |  
+-----------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Years**

```
+---------+
|    year |
+---------+
|    2017 |
|    2018 |
|    2019 |
|    2020 |
+---------+
```

**Months** (for 2020)

```
+-------------+
|       month |
+-------------+
|     january |
|    february |
|       march |
|       april |
|         may |
|        june |
|        july |
|      august |
|   september |
|     october |
|    november |
|    december |
+-------------+
```

**Time sheet** (for January)

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|       date |        task |   time_worked |   fixed_price |  
+------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 01-01-2020 |   Webdesign |             2 |             - |
| 02-01-2020 |        Logo |             - |           500 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I hardly know any MySQL (or backend in general) and I made the node CRUD connection with a tutorial - so I’m really having trouble getting my head around how to join the table and use the client_id as the main key/identifier. And also how to make it so that I can have a CRUD insdie my current CRUD so that I can create **new years** and **new lines in the time sheets**.

Maybe I’m going about it all wrong – I hope you can help.
Let me know if you need more info from me.

// Rue

Comment: the time sheet table needs a client_id column, then you can simply do another select, likewise if you wanted to track which developer did the work.. developer_id which links to a developer user table, the months and years tables are not needed as you already tracking it in `date` column

Comment: Good point about the month and years tables :) How do I make sure that it is the client_id from the clients table I have in the time sheet table?

Comment: when you insert the timesheet row, you would already have selected the client as part of validation that the work being added if for a valid/existing client.. i.e more code/logic

Comment: But how do I insert the timesheet row?